# Custom button of related list present in classic but missing in lightning

Tags: lightning, visualforce-component, button, migration, salesforce-classic

There is a custom onclick javascript button that is present in the related list layout of campaign object. but it is missing in lightning experience. need solutions on how to bring it

[image]

and the button is added in the related list properties as well [image]

Answer (score 1):

OnClick JavaScript buttons aren't supported in Lightning Experience. Follow this guide to learn about options and strategies for converting them:

[Convert JavaScript Buttons and Links into Lightning Experience Alternatives](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.lcc_javascript_buttons_overview.htm&type=5)